# How to display Google Analytics active users in commandline

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to fetch active users value on site from google analytics in linux command line ? I need real time stats for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it will involve you working with the API which requires authorization:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/

Comment: I didn't understand How can I start ?